# Finitely generated Ideals of finite algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

i would really appreciate any help with this question.
So, the question is:
**How to prove that finitely generated ideals of finite algebras over the ring F are finite over F?**
Thanks.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a *finite algebra* $A$ over the ring $F$?  Is $F$ itself a finite ring?  Note that $F$ is often used to denote a field rather than an arbitrary (possibly noncommutative?) ring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of simplicity (and since I come from the view of algebraic geometry/commutative algebra) I assume commutativity.

Let $F \to A$ be a finite ring map, i.e. $A$ is a $F$-algebra, that is finite as $F$-module and $I \subset A$ some finitely generated ideal. $A$ is a $F$-module via $F \to A$. We want to show that it is finite over $F$, i.e. a finitely generated $F$-module.

Since the sum of two finite $F$-modules is again finite, we can assume $I=(a)$ for some $a \in A$. We have a surjection $A \xrightarrow{\cdot a} I$.

By assumption we have a surjection $F^{\oplus n} \to A$, together with the surjection above this gives rise to a surjection

$$F^{\oplus n} \to A \xrightarrow{\cdot a} I,$$

which proves the statement.

Note: Reading through the proof again, this should also work well without commutativity.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, thats all clear, except $F^{\oplus n}$. What does it  mean?

Comment: It is just the direct sum of $n$ copies of $F$, i.e. the free module of rank $n$. One also writes simply $F^n$.